# VB6 code to create DLL to fetch data fom SAP BAPI, with parameter

Tags: dll, vb6, bapi

I am asking somebody to give VB6 code support to create a .DLL to fetch data from SAP BAPI. I don't have any idea what ActiveX control to use or where to get started. I am new in this kind of programming. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

VB6 - Difficult.

Your best bet is probably access the BAPI through web services (every BAPI is exposed as Web Service; at least in more recent SAP versions). But that does not seem to be that simple (google for it).

There was once a COM Component for accessing RFC functions, but that is no longer supported. The last option would be to use the RFC SDK and create a VB6 wrapper for accessing the exported functions in libRFC.dll (maybe not the easiest task).

Things get a lot more simple if you switch to VB.Net (or any other .Net language): There is a new version of the [SAP .Net Connector](http://wiki.sdn.sap.com/wiki/display/ABAPConn/ABAP+Connectivity+Home).